# Merging data from two files that contain the same column - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am attempting to

file1:

```
     #query_name KEGG_KOs
10  PROKKA_00019   K00240
11  PROKKA_00020   K00246
12  PROKKA_00022   K02887
```

file2:

```
Geneid  Chr Count
PROKKA_00019    k141_1000050    102
PROKKA_00020    k141_1000050    132
PROKKA_00021    k141_1000054    36
```

file3 (desired output):

```
Geneid  KEGG_KOs    Chr Count
PROKKA_00019    K00240  k141_1000050    102
PROKKA_00020    K00246  k141_1000050    132
```

This seems to be the correct script:

```
import pandas as pd
file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep="\t")
file2= pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep="\t")
file3= pd.merge(file1, file2, left_on='#query_name', right_on='Geneid').drop(['#query_name'],axis=1)
print(merged)
```

However, it returns a message of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**FilePath**C", line 4, in <module>
    merged = pd.merge(genes, counts, left_on='#query_name', right_on='Geneid').drop(['#query_name'],axis=1)
  File "**FilePath**", line 61, in merge
    validate=validate)
  File "**FilePath**", line 551, in __init__
    self.join_names) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "**FilePath**", line 871, in _get_merge_keys
    lk, stacklevel=stacklevel))
  File "**FilePath**", line 1382, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '#query_name'
```

I was thinking could be because of the space at the beginning of file1. But removing it and the index column created by a previous dataframe script didn't change anything. Anyone have any clues as to why or how to fix? Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

[image: @jezrael]

Comment: What return `print (file1.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael Hello again, it returns: ['     #query_name KEGG_KOs']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip first line - header of csv and set new columns names by parameter `names` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), then set same column like in `file2`, so `drop` is not necessary:

```
file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep="\t", skiprows=1, names=['Geneid','KEGG_KOs'])
print (file1)
          Geneid KEGG_KOs
10  PROKKA_00019   K00240
11  PROKKA_00020   K00246
12  PROKKA_00022   K02887

file2= pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep="\t")

file3= pd.merge(file1, file2, on='Geneid')
print(merged)
```

Comment: Nice, however, it returns: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Geneid, KEGG_KOs, Chr, Count]
Index: []

Comment: @gwrathe - Can you check `file1` if return 2 columns filled with correct data like in my answer?

Comment: It has created an extra column of 'NaN's :                       Geneid  KEGG_KOs
0  10  PROKKA_00019   K00240       NaN
1  11  PROKKA_00020   K00246       NaN
2  12  PROKKA_00022   K02887       NaN

Comment: @gwrathe - It seems whitespace is separator, how working `file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep="\s+", skiprows=1, names=['Geneid','KEGG_KOs'])` ?